# count only locally repeating rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array called 'a':

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[3,4]])
```

which looks like:

```
[[1 2]
 [1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]
 [3 4]]
```

what I want to do is this: if a row repeats itself without a different row in between, I want to count how many times is happens and create a vector of those counts. from every repetition, I want to leave only the first row. afterward, I want to stack the counts vector to the right side of the matrix, so I could see using the column how many times that row repeated itself in the original matrix. if the same row appears later in the matrix, it's a new count.

so after applying this, 'a' would be converted to:

```
[[1 2 2]
 [3 4 1]
 [5 6 1]
 [3 4 1]]
```

I tried solving this by:

```
def compress_mat(mat):
    unique, idx, counts = np.unique(mat, return_index=True, return_counts=True, axis=0)
    counts = np.expand_dims(np.array(counts), 1)
    unique = np.hstack([mat[np.sort(idx)], counts])
    return unique
```

but is groups repeated rows that are separated by other rows. for example, it will convert 'a' to:

```
[[1 2 2]
 [3 4 2]
 [5 6 1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't bother iterating the array manually, one possible solution is to iterate from `first index`, and for each index, to compare next sub arrays for equalities until they are unequal.
Create a dictionary that will hold index as key and counts as values.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[3,4]])

counts = {}
i = 0
while i < (a.shape[0]):
    count = 1
    next_index = i+1
    for j in range(i + 1, a.shape[0]):
        if all(a[i] == a[j]):
            count += 1
            next_index += 1    # Keep increasing index value for Truth condition
        else:
            counts[i] = count
            break     #Break inner loop if two sub arrays are not equal
    i = next_index    #Assign i to directly next index where equality is False
```

Now, if you print the dictionary, it looks like this: `{0: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1}`

At last, you need to check if the last element has been taken into account in this dictionary or not.

```py
if max(counts)+counts[max(counts)] != a.shape[0]:
    counts[a.shape[0]-1] = 1
```

Now it holds the indices and counts for all the values you need: `{0: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}`

Create a numpy array out of the values in this dictionary, and stack with the values at the indices given by keys:

```py
np.hstack((a[[*counts]], np.array([*counts.values()]).reshape(len(counts),1)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
array([[1, 2, 2],
       [3, 4, 1],
       [5, 6, 1],
       [3, 4, 1]])
```

Comment: ty! this is close to being a solution, but it does not remove the repeated rows -see example please.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got your point. Basically, the idea is that the same subsequent rows should not repeat